# Will Unity get removed during the next distro upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, 17.04

I am installing Ubuntu 17.04 today. I want to know that if during the 17.10 upgrade the Unity 7 get removed or not?

Answer (score 1):

The unity package will still exist and [be moved to the universe](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/unity) repo. If you have universe disabled, it might suggest removing the package, but you can say no to that.